# Shutdown node if systemd unit failed to restart

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to shut down a host if systemd unit failed to restart after several attempts? Something like "Systemd-based STONITH" )))

Is there maybe hooks or dependencies mechanism in unit-files?

Comment: If you are open to a solution that is not using systemd, just tell me, and I will post answer.

Comment: yes, you can tell. would you like to propose software watchdog?

Comment: do you want the app to be automatically restarted on another node after node shutdown ?

Comment: no, i just want to shutdown a node if unit fails to restart

Comment: ok. no solution, sorry.